# delimiter or removing vertical bars using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have parsed data that has vertical bars beside the contents.

like this:

```
 0  00:00|  4323    548|    0   0|  0   0|  0   0|  0   0|  0   0|  18
```

how do I remove the vertical bars using the delimiter function? I only seem to make it work on whitespaces. Here's my code.

```
df = pd.read_csv('sampleData1.txt', header=None, delimiter=r"\s+", engine='python', skiprows=0, sep='|', names=['time_pd','group_call_t_s','group_call_t_c','pvt_call_t_sec','pvt_call_t_c','phone_call_t_sec','phone_call_t_c','group_busy_t_sec','group_busy_t_c','pvt_busy_t_sec','pvt_busy_t_c','phone_busy_t_sec','phone_busy_t_c','per_usage'])

df.to_csv('sampleOutput1.csv', index = None)

df
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work replacing

```
delimiter=r"\s+"
```

with

```
delimiter="|"
```

Remove this field: `sep='|'`